# OpenCV error while compiling ros workspace

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ros

recently, after installing OpenCV3, I am not able to use [Baxter](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Baxter_Setup) on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS. However, I removed OpenCV3 later on but the `catkin_make` on ros indigo workspace is giving following error-

```
Linking CXX executable /home/ravi/ros_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_hardware/baxter_emulator
[100%] Built target baxter_sim_io
CMakeFiles/baxter_emulator.dir/src/baxter_emulator.cpp.o: In function `baxter_en::baxter_emulator::publish(std::string const&)':
baxter_emulator.cpp:(.text+0x2087): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/baxter_emulator.dir/src/baxter_emulator.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
baxter_emulator.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/baxter_emulator.dir/src/baxter_emulator.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::string const&)':
baxter_emulator.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2ERKSs[_ZN2cv6StringC5ERKSs]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/ravi/ros_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_hardware/baxter_emulator] Error 1
make[1]: *** [baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_hardware/CMakeFiles/baxter_emulator.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

OpenCV3 was installed from the source using [this script](https://github.com/milq/scripts-ubuntu-debian/blob/master/install-opencv.sh). This script has installed some additional libraries as well. I removed OpenCV3 by following command-

```
cd OpenCV/build
sudo make unistall
sudo ldconfig
```

but catkin_make is still showing same error.

Comment: Do you have any other version of opencv installed?

Comment: I am not sure. but before installing OpenCV3, the catkin_make was working. It stopped working after installing OpenCV3. Though I have removed OpenCV3 but problem still persists. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Now its not working because it can not find opencv. What was the error when opencv was installed?

Comment: OpenCV was installed from source using make command. There was not error while installation. In fact, OpenCV3 was working like a charm. But since catkin_make stopped working, so I had to remove it.

Comment: My question was, what was this catkin_make error you were getting

Comment: I have Baxter SDK installed in ROS workspace. I am just trying to compile it. The error comes when I run `catkin_make` command in ROS workspace. Just for information, OpenCV 2.x is officially supported for Baxter SDK.

Comment: If you install opencv again, what is the output of running catkin_make?

Comment: @RaviJoshi ROS Indigo is also supported with OpenCV 2.x. Have you tried to reinstall opencv 2.4 after removing version 3 ?

Comment: @marcoresk: No, I haven't installed opencv 2.4 by myself. I actually reinstalled ROS Indigo.